# How can I output the result of atof as 1.0 instead of 1

Tags: c++, string-formatting

I have a problem using atof,
here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::string num ("1.0");
    //std::string num ("1.1");
    cout<< atof(num.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

If the num string is "1.1" , it can correctly cout 1.1. But if I want to keep the zero when the num string is "1.0" (want it to be 1.0 but not 1), what should I do?

Comment: What you need is `std::setprecision`. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) you can see an example.

Comment: This is nothing to do with `atof`, it's a question of specifying output formatting.  You'd see the same thing if you did `cout << 1.0`.

Comment: this looks way more like `C` code than `C++`. Anyway you are probably interested in `sscanf`.

Comment: @user2485710: Almost none of this is C code...

Comment: Look up `iomanip` and `setprecision`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yeah, but `atof` it's not exactly C++ and a `const char*` it's not exactly a C++-ish type ...

Comment: What if I need the atof(string) became a Parameter to be passed to other functions. What should I do now? It's not under the cout condition actually.@JoeZ

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) and [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision), like so:

```
std::cout<< std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << atof(num.c_str());
```

This will require that you include the [iomanip](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) header.

Comment: What if I need the atof(string) became a Parameter to be passed to other functions. What should I do now? It's not under the cout condition actually.

Comment: @user3097625 you have no control then. A floating point value doesn't keep track of the number of significant digits.

Comment: @user3097625: There's a special branch of math (interval arithmetic) that deals with that. You need a special type for that, because every operator needs to change. E.g, `(1 ± 0.5) * (1 ± 0.5)` = `1.25 ± 1`  !

Comment: @user3097625 it is not entirely clear to me what you want to do but Mark's comment probably sums it up. If my answer was not useful at all, let me know and I will delete it. For future reference you need to be very specific on what problem you are attempting to solve since the solution may be very sensitive to the context.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
  std::cout.precision(3);
  std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
  std::string s("1.0");
  float f = 0.0f;
  sscanf(s.c_str(), "%f", &f);
  // alternative way of setting this flags
  // std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << f << "\n";
  std::cout << f << "\n";
  return (0);
}
```

notice that there are at least 2 ways of accomplishing the same format for the output, I left one of them commented out .

Comment: What if I need the atof(string) became a Parameter to be passed to other functions. What should I do now? It's not under the cout condition actually.Thx

Comment: `atof` returns a `double` not a `float`, you need to cast the result to a float if you need a float; if you need to pass the value to a function you just include the call to `atof` inside the call to a function. example `foo((float)atof("1.1"))` where the function `foo` takes a `float` as parameter.